# Configuring spring-rabbit queue address to be changeable in runtime

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, message-queue

Here is a web app listening a RabbitMQ queue. Everything works fine, but it is inacceptable that host address of the queue (127.0.0.1) is hardcoded in spring xml config.

How can I have the host to be configured on the fly, from an external registry?

The host address may change during app life. I'd prefer if spring asked some custom written method for the queue address every time it is needed.

```
<rabbit:queue id="myQueue" />
<rabbit:topic-exchange id="myExchange" name="my-exchange">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="myQueue" pattern="my.#.*">
        </rabbit:binding>
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:topic-exchange>
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="127.0.0.1" username="test" password="test" />
<bean id="queListener" class="my.QueListener" />
<rabbit:listener-container id="myListenerContainer" connection-factory="connectionFactory">
    <rabbit:listener ref="queListener" queues="myQueue" />
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

Spring 4.1,
spring-jms,
spring-rabbit:1.5,
jboss 6.4 eap

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. Probably it has some issues but basically it works.

```
private SimpleMessageListenerContainer container;
private static CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

// 1. stop existing consumer

if (container != null) {
    container.stop();
}
if (connectionFactory != null) {
   connectionFactory.destroy();
}

// 2. re-create consumer from scratch
//    imagine all string constants comes from a config

CachingConnectionFactory cf = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
connectionFactory = cf;
cf.setUsername("tst");
cf.setPassword("tst");

RabbitAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(cf);
Queue queue = new Queue("myQueue");
admin.declareQueue(queue);
TopicExchange exchange = new TopicExchange("myExchange");
admin.declareExchange(exchange);
admin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(routingKey));

SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);
Object listener = new Object() {
    public void handleMessage(byte[] message) { ... }
};
MessageListenerAdapter adapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(listener);
container.setMessageListener(adapter);
container.setQueueNames(queueName);
container.start();
```